# How to submit two forms this way with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, form-submit

```
<form id="form1">...</form>
<form id="form2">...</form>
```

I want to submit `form1` to `host1` first for validation,if the response is `true` then submit `form2` to `host2`,both should be using `POST`.

How to do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an implementation using AJAX

```
$("#form1").submit(function(){
    $.post( $(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(),
        function(){
            $.post( $("#form2").attr("action"), $("#form2").seriallize(),
                function(){
                    alert("Now what?");
                });
        });
});
```

Here instead of checking for the response to be 'true' I just assume that it will only have a successful response if the validation passes as 'true'

Answer (score 2):

Do an AJAX call, on success do another. here is the [API Link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)